# Porting a GTK+ App to Mac OSX

Tags: macos, gtk, porting

I have a GTK+ Application (ready with Autotools) which i have developed on my Linux box. Now I need to port this one to OSX. 
I have successfully installed jhbuild, which in turn installed GTK+ and stuff on the Mac (10.5.8)

I just don't know what to do next. Trying to ./configure && make && make install (on my app copied to the Mac) fails since pkg-config is not installed on the Mac.

Do I really need to write a jhbuild moduleset in order to compile this app?
I need two libraries as well: libxml2 and libsoup-2.4. Will jhbuild tae care for integrating them...?!

My question now is: What is the simplest way to port a GTK+ Application to OSX and is there a tutorial or how-to on it?

Answer (score 8):

I recommend installing [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) which is a command line package manager for mac. Once installed open terminal and run `brew install pkg-config` to install pkg-config then `brew install gtk+` and/or `brew install gtk+3` to install gtk+ 2 or 3 respectively.
After that is done you should be able to compile with your makefiles.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that jhbuild installed GTK? Did you do

```
jhbuild bootstrap
jhbuild build meta-gtk-osx-bootstrap
jhbuild build meta-gtk-osx-core
```

as instructed on the ["GTK OSX Building"](http://live.gnome.org/GTK%2B/OSX/Building) page? If you did this, then pkg-config is *definitely* installed, because those packages wouldn't have built without it.

Are you building your application from within the jhbuild environment? i.e. did you do

```
jhbuild shell
```

before trying to build your application?

Comment: Ok, thank you - i just realized that i have to do a "jhbuild shell" and then configure/make from within this shell. I managed to get my app compiled but now when i start the app it is crashing with a "Dbus error"...

Answer (score 0):

Isn't using jhbuild a bit overkill ? Wouldn't a [Mac OS X GTK bundle from gtk.org](http://www.gtk.org/download/macos.php) be enough ? I think it provides pkg-config as the Win32 version provides it. Jhbuild is interesting if you have tons of dependencies to build, or want to build GTK yourself, but from what I understand, you just want to port a GTK application...

Comment: Oh -ok. I would really like to have a more simple way to do this. You are right: I just want to port this app so that it runs on Mac OSX. Could you be so kind and give me one more point what exactly i would have to do? The site you have linked was my starting point as well and I understood, that i would need to use jhbuild and all that stuff. Where can i download this Mac OSX GTK bundle and how do i install it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, seems I was wrong here. I know GTK on Linux and Win32, but never used the Mac port. The instructions on [that page](Building GTK-OSX) are about building GTK for OS X, but also for building the apps, which is not that clear on the gtk.org page. Even the bundles which are mentioned are different from what is called "bundle" in the Win32 port of GTK (which is a binary pre-compiled pakage - no need to rebuild GTK). So yes, from reading the informations there, it seems you'll have to use jhbuild and build the whole stack to be able to build you .

Comment: Right, you absolutely need jhbuild (or MacPorts) for any development. The "bundles" they are talking about are `.app` packages of your application with the GTK library stack included inside them, so that your app user doesn't have to download and compile GTK him/herself.